# How to apply multiple formating on single field in xml odoo?

Tags: xml, formatting, odoo

I want to apply formatting according to my field value if value in selection field is 'open', 'pending' and 'solved' colors should be 'red', 'blue' and 'grey' respectively.

```
<field name = 'status' widget="selection" attrs="{'invisible':[('type','=','open')]}" style="color:red;" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<field name = 'status' widget="selection" decoration-danger="status=='open'" decoration-info="status=='pending'" decoration-muted="status=='solved'"/>
```

It is working for me.

Comment: Does this changes the selected value or the entire field?

Comment: No, just upcoming value formatting will change according to this. Upcoming value may be 'open', 'pending' or 'solved' whatever the value is just the formatting of that word will change.

Comment: Upvote easier than my solution, but you are limited to list of color

Comment: @CharifDZ exactly you are right that is the only limitation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `t-att-style` attribute instead of `style`

Eg :

`t-att-style="'color: #f00;' if type == 'open' else ('color: #00f;' if type == 
     'pending' else 'color: #696969;')"`

Try this one (May have some changes)

Comment: @adamStrauss Not working ?
Take a look at this module, https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/web_tree_dynamic_colored_field/, Think will helpfull.

Comment: I think if I am not wrong you are giving me the reference of some other module's documentation.
If I want that feature I have to install that module right?
If yes then sorry I cant because I want it without any other module installation.